# Is there a problem with using textures I drew in Paint?

Tags: c++, opengl

As the title says, I'm trying to render a cube using the code below (plus a custom Shader class and the actual shaders omitted for brevity) to render a tilted cube turning on the Y axis.

The problem is with the texture: if I just download some `.png` from Google Images it renders just fine, but if I create some random texture using MS Paint and **only change the file path to said MS Paint texture** I get an `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA3BEADB68 (nvoglv64.dll) in Untitled_OpenGL_Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001F6A94A2000.` exception.

What is the problem? Is it something to do with the value for transparent pixels or something? (grasping at straws here)

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "Shader.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "stb_image.h"

int main()
{
    // Setup 
    if (!Utility::glfwSetup())
        return -1;

    GLFWwindow* window = Utility::glfwOpenWindow(Utility::SCREEN_WIDTH, Utility::SCREEN_HEIGHT, "GLFW Window");
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!Utility::gladSetup())
        return -1;

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, Utility::key_callback);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Program
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    float vertices[] = {
        // Position          // Texel
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };  
    unsigned int indices[] = {  
         0,  1,  3,
         0,  2,  3,

         4,  5,  7,
         4,  6,  7,

         8,  9, 11,
         8, 10, 11,

        12, 13, 15,
        12, 14, 15,

        16, 17, 19,
        16, 18, 19,

        20, 21, 23,
        20, 22, 23
    };

    // Buffer setup
    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    unsigned int EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    float tiltAngle = 70.0f;

    // MVP
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::vec3 zAxis = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    model = glm::rotate(model, (float) glm::radians(tiltAngle), zAxis);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float) Utility::SCREEN_WIDTH / Utility::SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // Texture
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    Utility::texSetup(GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT, GL_NEAREST, GL_LINEAR);

    int width, height, numChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("res/textures/BlackFrame.png", &width, &height, &numChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    // Shader setup
    Shader shader("res/shaders/VertexShader.shader", "res/shaders/FragShader.shader");
    glUseProgram(shader.ID);
    shader.setUniformMat4f(model, "model");
    shader.setUniformMat4f(view, "view");
    shader.setUniformMat4f(proj, "proj");
    shader.setUniform1i(0, "texture1");

    // Time
    float prevTime = (float)glfwGetTime();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Setup
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Input
        Utility::processInput(window);

        // Rendering
        float curTime = (float)glfwGetTime();
        float deltaTime = curTime - prevTime;
        prevTime = curTime;

        // Rotate around Y axis
        glm::vec3 yAxis = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        model = glm::rotate(model, (float)glm::radians(-tiltAngle), zAxis);
        model = glm::rotate(model, deltaTime, yAxis);
        model = glm::rotate(model, (float)glm::radians(tiltAngle), zAxis);
        shader.setUniformMat4f(model, "model");

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Clean-up
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

utils.cpp:

```
int Utility::glfwSetup()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, VERSION_MAJOR);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, VERSION_MINOR);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    std::cout << "GLFW " << VERSION_MAJOR << "." << VERSION_MINOR << " initialized successfully." << std::endl;

    return 1;
}

int Utility::gladSetup()
{
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void Utility::texSetup(int wrapParamS, int wrapParamT, int minParam, int magParam)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

    float borderColor[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapParamS);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapParamT);
    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minParam);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magParam);
}

GLFWwindow* Utility::glfwOpenWindow(int width, int height, const char* title)
{
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return NULL;
    }

    return window;
}

void Utility::processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to find where the code is crashing?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm drawing in MS Paint and saving as a PNG

@AlanBirtles I did, it crashes at ```glTexImage2D```. I looked it up on docs.gl but the errors don't seem to match my problem.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Line 124 in main.cpp, ```glTexImage2D```

Comment: @AntonLoubman What do you get for `numChannels`? Try to force 4 channels: `stbi_load(..., 4);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 amazing, it worked! I got 3 channels but your trick did get it to work. Any explanation for this? How come it happens for MS Paint in particular? (Would you mind posting the comment as an answer so I can mark it answered?)

Comment: @AntonLoubman Paint doesn't support alpha channels. `stbi_load` will return an image with the minimum required channels unless you specify something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that a PNG file has 4 channels or that `stbi_load` will return an image with 4 channels.

`stbi_load` can be forced to generate an image with 4 color channels, by explicitly pass 4 to the last parameter:

<s>`unsigned char* data = stbi_load("BlackFrame.png", &width, &height, &numChannels, 0);`</s>

```cpp
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("BlackFrame.png", &width, &height, &numChannels, 4);
```

See [stb_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h):

> ```
> Basic usage (see HDR discussion below for HDR usage):
>      int x,y,n;
>      unsigned char *data = stbi_load(filename, &x, &y, &n, 0);
>      // ... process data if not NULL ...
>      // ... x = width, y = height, n = # 8-bit components per pixel ...
>      // ... replace '0' with '1'..'4' to force that many components per pixel
>      // ... but 'n' will always be the number that it would have been if you said 0
>      stbi_image_free(data);
> ```